# Using sp_execute_external_script, how can I route the metadata of a trained model to output_data_1

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2016

R-Integration to SQL Server 2016 (CTP3):
I am using the new sp_execute_external_script to create a linear regression model. Is there a way to send the coefficients data about the trained model to output_data_1_name ?

For example, in the body of the R-Script, if you issue:  print(myModel);
It prints this in the SSMS output window  (not output_data):

```
Call:
lm(formula = DepVar ~ IndepVar1 + IndepVar2, data = myDemoData)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)       IndepVar1  IndepVar2
      123.456       25.456     56.382
```

Is it possible to get this into a data frame?  That would be preferable, as I also want to get the t-values and R-squared and store it to a table.  Even a varchar(max) would be fine.  I'd just parse it myself.

Here is what I've tried most recently:

```
declare @rx_model varbinary(max) = (select model from dbo.Mymodel)
exec dbo.sp_execute_external_script 
@language              = N'R',
@script                = N'require("RevoScaleR");
Mymodel                <- unserialize(rx_model);
Mymodelsummary         = summary(Mymodel);
A1 = Mymodelsummary[1]; 
A2 = Mymodelsummary[2];
A3 = Mymodelsummary[3];
A4 = Mymodelsummary[4];
A5 = Mymodelsummary[5];
summary_Text = data.frame( c(A4, A5) ); ', 
@input_data_1          = N'', 
@input_data_1_name     = N'', 
@output_data_1_name    = N'summary_Text',
@params                = N'@rx_model varbinary(max)', 
@rx_model              = @rx_model
with result sets (("A4" nvarchar(max), "A5" nvarchar(max) ));
```

The error I'm getting in SQL Server 2016 CTP3 is:

Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 0
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script'
with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
An external script error occurred: 
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
cannot coerce class ""summary.rxLinMod"" to a data.frame
Calls: source ... data.frame -> as.data.frame -> as.data.frame.default
Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
Execution halted
Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 
1 result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time.

So I'm wondering how to get that output out of sp_execute_external_script in SQL.  MSDN does not cover much about R itself.  SQL is complaining that the output from the model cannot be "coerced" to a data frame.  I'm wondering what manipulation in the R-Script can be done to "tease" it into a dataframe.

Comment: have a look at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604368.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response Hubert.  Yes, I've practically memorized that page, as well as many other.  I may have found something close to a solution on this.  Here's what I'm dealing with:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a `nvarchar`, you can try something like:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R'
, @script = N'
mymodel <- lm(formula = DepVar ~ IndepVar1 + IndepVar2, data = myDemoData);
coefficients <- paste(names(mymodel$coefficients), mymodel$coefficients, sep="=", collapse = " ");
'
, @input_data_1 = N'select DepVar, IndepVar1, IndepVar2 from myDemoData'
, @input_data_1_name = N'myDemoData'
, @output_data_1_name = N'coefficients'
WITH RESULT SETS (( coefficients nvarchar(max)));
```

this should return the string

```
"(Intercept)=123.456 IndepVar1=25.456 IndepVar2=56.382"
```

Comment: This is very close to what I needed. We do need to put two single quotes around the equals sign sep is assigned to. (it's inside a text string)

OutputDataSet          <- data.frame( paste(names(Mymodel$coefficients), Mymodel$coefficients, sep=''='', collapse = " "));',

then on the Result set:
WITH RESULT SETS  (( OutputDataSet nvarchar(max) ))

I will look into the paste and names functions to see how to get at the model metadata now.   Thank you very much!!

Comment: Why did you have to transform the string into a `data.frame`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert the model into data frame per se to return to SQL. If you want to store the entire model in the database, then you can transform to raw vector in R and return it as a a varbinary(max) output parameter in T-SQL. Alternatively, you can extract the individual components from the model like coefficients, error as individual / scalar values and return to SQL.

Here is an example that extracts coefficients as a data frame:

```
    execute sp_execute_external_script
      @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'
irisModel <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species, data = iris);
irisCoeff <- summary(irisModel)$coefficients;
OutputDataSet <- cbind(name = row.names(irisCoeff), data.frame(irisCoeff));
'
with result sets((Name nvarchar(100), "Estimate" float, "Std.Error" float, "t.value" float, "Pr.value" float))
```